# Disposing Graphics2D objects created by Graphics2D.create();

Tags: java, graphics2d

For the purpose a graphical program I am creating right now I am creating forks of a Graphics2D instance using `Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gOrig.create();`. What I am wondering is if I should be using the `g.dispose();` method after I am finished with this fork, or if that is handled automatically by the under workings of Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, definitely dispose of this Graphics object. Dispose of all Graphics or Graphics2D objects that **you** create as this will help clean up resources that are no longer needed.

But dispose of none of the Graphics objects given to you by the JVM as a parameter to a painting method such as `public void paint(Graphics g)` or `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Disposing of these risks breaking the painting chain as these Graphics objects are often needed down-stream by child components, borders, and the like.